# Can't complie exe's in Python

Tags: python

I apologise because this question has probably been asked a trillion times although I wasn't able to find any solutions.

I've been having trouble compiling apps I have tried pyinstaller and Auto py to exe without any luck.

I'm going to attach my logs to see if any of you have an idea of what is going on.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Auto py to exe doesn't show any error:

```
Running auto-py-to-exe v2.13.0
Building directory: C:\Users\Matteo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkgynawn1
Provided command: pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --console  "C:/AutoPrint/AutoPrint/New folder/AutoPrint.py"
Recursion Limit is set to 5000
Executing: pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --console C:/AutoPrint/AutoPrint/New folder/AutoPrint.py --distpath C:\Users\Matteo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkgynawn1\application --workpath C:\Users\Matteo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkgynawn1\build --specpath C:\Users\Matteo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkgynawn1

102422 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.7
102424 INFO: Python: 3.10.1
102448 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19043-SP0
102451 INFO: wrote C:\Users\Matteo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkgynawn1\AutoPrint.spec
102456 INFO: UPX is not available.
102471 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\AutoPrint\\AutoPrint\\New folder']
102709 INFO: checking Analysis
102710 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
102718 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
102737 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
102753 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
106317 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'C:\\Users\\Matteo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
106330 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'C:\\Users\\Matteo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib'
107416 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
107574 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
107599 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by C:\Users\Matteo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
107649 INFO: Analyzing C:\AutoPrint\AutoPrint\New folder\AutoPrint.py
107743 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook six.moves from 'C:\\Users\\Matteo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-six.moves.py'.
107952 INFO: Processing module hooks...
107964 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pynput.py' from 'C:\\Users\\Matteo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
108180 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-difflib.py' from 'C:\\Users\\Matteo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
108186 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from 'C:\\Users\\Matteo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
108200 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.util.py' from 'C:\\Users\\Matteo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
108217 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'C:\\Users\\Matteo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
108298 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from 'C:\\Users\\Matteo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
108310 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lib2to3.py' from 'C:\\Users\\Matteo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
108400 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-multiprocessing.util.py' from 'C:\\Users\\Matteo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
108405 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from 'C:\\Users\\Matteo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
108422 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sysconfig.py' from 'C:\\Users\\Matteo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
108435 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py' from 'C:\\Users\\Matteo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
108439 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from 'C:\\Users\\Matteo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
108511 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-_tkinter.py' from 'C:\\Users\\Matteo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
108647 INFO: checking Tree
108653 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-00.toc is non existent
108656 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc
108717 INFO: checking Tree
108720 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-01.toc is non existent
108733 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc
108819 INFO: checking Tree
108826 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-02.toc is non existent
108828 INFO: Building Tree Tree-02.toc
108854 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
108876 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
108890 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\Matteo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_inspect.py'
108904 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\Matteo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pkgutil.py'
108921 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\Matteo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
108936 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\Matteo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
108955 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
109164 INFO: Looking for eggs
109169 INFO: Using Python library C:\Users\Matteo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python310.dll
109184 INFO: Found binding redirects: 
[]
109204 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\Matteo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkgynawn1\build\AutoPrint\warn-AutoPrint.txt
109281 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\Matteo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkgynawn1\build\AutoPrint\xref-AutoPrint.html
109333 INFO: checking PYZ
109341 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
109356 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\Matteo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkgynawn1\build\AutoPrint\PYZ-00.pyz
109822 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\Matteo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkgynawn1\build\AutoPrint\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
109840 INFO: checking PKG
109856 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
109872 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) AutoPrint.pkg
109909 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) AutoPrint.pkg completed successfully.
109921 INFO: Bootloader C:\Users\Matteo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\run.exe
109935 INFO: checking EXE
109951 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
109966 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
109972 INFO: Copying bootloader EXE to C:\Users\Matteo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkgynawn1\build\AutoPrint\AutoPrint.exe
109992 INFO: Copying icon to EXE
110014 INFO: Copying icons from ['C:\\Users\\Matteo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\bootloader\\images\\icon-console.ico']
110033 INFO: Writing RT_GROUP_ICON 0 resource with 104 bytes
110039 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 1 resource with 3752 bytes
110061 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 2 resource with 2216 bytes
110075 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 3 resource with 1384 bytes
110092 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 4 resource with 37019 bytes
110107 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 5 resource with 9640 bytes
110123 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 6 resource with 4264 bytes
110127 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 7 resource with 1128 bytes
110141 INFO: Copying 0 resources to EXE
110145 INFO: Emedding manifest in EXE
110155 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\Matteo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkgynawn1\build\AutoPrint\AutoPrint.exe
110232 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 1 language 0
110252 INFO: Appending PKG archive to EXE
110756 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
110763 INFO: checking COLLECT
110772 INFO: Building COLLECT because COLLECT-00.toc is non existent
110787 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc
112041 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc completed successfully.

Moving project to: C:\Users\Matteo\output
Complete.
```

Altough when I try to run the app it doesn't open.

Thoughts?

This is the code I'm trying to compile

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as font
import os
import glob
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller, Listener
import ctypes
import keyboard

# improve resolution
ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(True)

keyboard = Controller()

# values for widgets' coordinates
ref_x=0
ref_y=0

# create window
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('650x400')
window.configure(bg='#fdfdfd')
window.title('AutoPrint')
myFont = font.Font(family='Calibri', size=13)

# create entrybox with label
entrybox = tk.Entry(window, width=28)
entrybox.place(x=ref_x + 200, y=ref_y + 10)
entrybox['font'] = myFont
entrybox.focus()

boxlabel = tk.Label(window, text='Scan Barcode:', bg='#fdfdfd')
boxlabel.place(x=ref_x + 15, y=ref_y + 10)
boxlabel['font'] = myFont

# define search funtions
def sendprint():
    word = entrybox.get()
    folder = r'C:\AutoPrint'    
    pattern = os.path.join(folder, f'*{word}*')
    fileExt = r".ar3"
    print('pattern:', pattern)
    filenames = glob.glob(pattern)
    print('filenames:', filenames)
    
    if filenames:
       os.startfile(filenames[0])
       time.sleep(3)
       keyboard.press(Key.enter)
       time.sleep(0.5)
       keyboard.release(Key.enter)
       print (filenames)
 
    else:
       print ('Not found')    

# create button
print_button = tk.Button(window, text='Print', command=sendprint, width=15, bg='#00a2ed', fg='white')
print_button.place(x=ref_x + 220, y=ref_y + 280)
print_button['font'] = myFont
```

Comment: PyInstaller doesn't 'compile' Python into an exe at all - it allows you to create an exe that unpacks Python and all the required packages on the computer where it runs and runs the script using that - but that's very different from using a compiled language's binary like an .exe compiled from C code for example.

Comment: Thanks @Grismar, I understand! So what is your suggestion for saving the file into exe in order to be opened on any computer?

Comment: I did not want to discourage you from using PyInstaller, it's a good way to get it to work on any computer without requiring Python to already be installed and configured with a suitable environment - but I just wanted to let you know that it's not at all the same thing and as a result, it doesn't work the same and also doesn't always work for any script, depending on the script's requirements.

Comment: I see, what would your suggestion be on troubleshooting why pyinstaller doesn't produce a working .exe if it doesn't return any error? is there anywhere else I can look? I am asking because there is something wrong at the base because it doesn't even compile a simple hello world program

Comment: I'm not familiar with auto-py-to-exe, but I would suggest looking at the basic documentation and how to get started for PyInstaller itself - it's not overly complicated to get your script packaged without a GUI and if you run into a specific problem, there's likely answers to be found on StackOverflow. Your current question isn't very specific - you ran some tool from a package, there were no error messages, but it didn't work. Since we don't have access to your source or setup, it's impossible to say what the issue is.

Comment: open your program from the cmd.exe, the error message will stay after the program closes.

Comment: @ahmed AEK I opened it trough CMD and no error showed up

Comment: I found the bugger, I was missing window.mainloop() at the end! Thanks everyone for the support

Answer (score 0):

Check that all program files that appeared after compiling are in the same folder as executable. If they are in the same folder and still doesn't work, try deleting all program files and compiling again.